# Why the chain of functions does not work in PHP?

Tags: php, yii, anonymous-methods

I was writing code for YIi, fileuploading.

When I write this:

```
$model->album_photocover = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'album_photocover');

$model->album_photocover->saveAs($path . '/' . $model->album_photocover);
```

it works.

```
     CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'album_photocover')->saveAs($path . '/' . $model->album_photocover);
```

But not the below one.
Its only same code but written in one line. I hope you got it simply.

Comment: Any errors? A log file?

Comment: I suspect the two of first line of codes that you said it worked. How could the $model->album_photocover that you set into object be appended such a string on second line? May I be missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your "one-line-solution", when you **valorize** *$model->album_photocover* that you use to compose the save path?

```
CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'album_photocover')
       ->saveAs($path . '/' . $model->album_photocover);
//____________________________^++++++++++++++++++++++^
```

**ADD**
I seen now @Telvin Nguyen comment, yep, that's the problem!